# Keep on getting a php artisan migrate error on laravel while using a MAMP server?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mamp

I am using a MAMP server to host my laravel project. I am trying to push my database migrations table which I have created to the MAMP phpmyadmin database hosted on the localhost 8888 server.

However everytime I use the command , `php artisan migrate` I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I have tried everything to change stuff in the .env file and the database.php file but nothing seems to be changing.

This is what my .env file looks like(only relevant parts):

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:H5A9PbNQk0we6UJnNzSZ68Y22B88SK6wCEq2wachQfE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD="temp"
UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This is what my database.php file looks like:

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'temp'),
            'unix_socket' => env( 'DB_SOCKET','/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Here is a picture of what the user accounts look like, what I have available:
[image]

Comment: when you use phpMyAdmin to access your database, you use `root` as username and `temp` as password ?

Comment: use username and password without double quotes in .env then try.

Comment: @N69S actually now I've changed it root and Yes

Comment: But it still doesn't seem to execute the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure u use the right username and password in phpmyadmin
And replace them in .env file and config/database.php file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try running php artisan config:clear and also php artisan cache:clear.

If that won't help try and login to the database using command line or bash if the credentials work.